# Mysql count and concatenate multiple text rows - is possible?

Tags: mysql, string, count, textfield

i've 2 table, one with user comments,
and another one with the list of single click on "I Like" button

```
TABLE COMMENTS

id | comment | data
---|---------|------
1  | blabla  | 12345
2  | hello   | 12345
3  | hi      | 12345
4  | test    | 12345
5  | yuhuu   | 12345
6  | dunno   | 12345
7  | hello   | 12345
8  | blabla  | 12345
9  | test    | 12345

TABLE ILIKE

id | comment_id | name
---|------------|------
1  | 5          | Peter
2  | 8          | Tim
3  | 5          | Joe
4  | 5          | Peter
5  | 3          | Joe
6  | 8          | Joe
7  | 8          | Peter
8  | 5          | 
9  | 3          | Joe
10 | 2          | 
11 | 2          |
```

Now i would count how many I like i have for each comments AND....
show the list of the username of the people who commented...

so the result table should be... something like that:

```
TABLE RESULT

id | comment | data  | totlike | from_names
---|---------|-------|---------|--------
1  | blabla  | 12345 | 0       |
2  | hello   | 12345 | 2       |
3  | hi      | 12345 | 2       | Joe
4  | test    | 12345 | 0       |
5  | yuhuu   | 12345 | 4       | Joe, Peter           //double name appears just one time
6  | dunno   | 12345 | 0       |
7  | hello   | 12345 | 0       |
8  | blabla  | 12345 | 3       | Joe, Peter, Tim      //if possible order in alphabetic order
9  | test    | 12345 | 0       |
```

if possible i dont want duplicate names
I try here but i can do the count staff but not the "join strings" parts...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c9b1d/2

who can solve this?

```
SELECT comments.id, comments.comment, count(ilike.id) as count
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN ilike on ilike.comment_id=comments.id
WHERE 1 GROUP BY comments.id
```

thank u,
N.

Comment: there's `group_concat()` for this sort of thing, but by default it's limited to 1024 chars and WILL silently truncate your list of names if it exceeds that limit.

Comment: just a quick thought, why a user is allowed to like the comment more than once?

Comment: becouse could be different people with the same name :) -BTW double voting is avoid by php script checking IP address-

Comment: then you should use user's login name rather than their first name otherwise when peter dislikes he would still see his name on the list and will confuse him. @user2846399

Comment: I agree, should be so... but the website is just a easy blog, without login. Every guest can comment and press "i like" (only one time for each IP). The name is just a cookie if that user has commented some post before (..and OPS doesnt exist disklike option yet.. ;) nice suggestion!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
GROUP_CONCAT(ILIKE.name ORDER BY ILIKE.name)
```

To create your comma-separated list.

Also, be careful.  You're using the non-standard MySQL extension to GROUP BY.  You seem to be using it correctly, but any changes in your query may change that. If you switched to

```
GROUP BY comments.id, comments.comment
```

you would no longer be depending on that extension.

Comment: i would slap a "distinct" to your answer to get unique names like: GROUP_CONCAT(distinct ILIKE.name ORDER BY ILIKE.name) :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

```
SELECT comments.id, comments.comment, count(ilike.id) as count,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT NULLIF(ILIKE.name,'') ORDER BY ILIKE.name) as from_names
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN ilike on ilike.comment_id=comments.id
WHERE 1 GROUP BY comments.id, comments.comment
```

thank u guys!